Ошибка при запуске бота: environs.EnvError: Environment variable "TOKEN" not set
При запуске бота выдаёт ошибку в этой части кода
from environs import Env
from dataclasses import dataclass



@dataclass
class Bots:
    bot_token: str
    admin_id: int

@dataclass
class Settings:
    bots: Bots


def get_settings(path: str):
    env = Env()
    env.read_env(path)

    return Settings(
        bots=Bots(
            bot_token=env.str("TOKEN"),
            admin_id=env.int("ADMIN_ID")
        )
    )

settings = get_settings('input')
print(settings)

Конкретно этот фрагмент кода не мой и взят из ресурса 2022 года, TOKEN и ADMIN_ID находятся в текстовом файле input
TOKEN=12345
ADMIN_ID=12345

Написано всё как и в источнике, следственно в чём ошибка не понимаю.
